# mac os x : Is possible to run an application that use mono without mono installed?

Tags: macos, mono

I am trying to use mono to compile .Net projects on MAC OS X. So , when i generate the app and if any other machine try to run it.. needs to have mono framework installed to run the application?

Which alternatives i have to solve this situation?..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xamarin.Mac, you can publish your app with Mono runtime bundled easily,

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_to_the_app_store/bundling/

If you don't want to use Xamarin.Mac, you can manually use AOT,

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/